# Cannot run a simple class when running a java program

Tags: java

I have created a directory `c:\ivankatrump` and in it i have the file `Trump.java`

```
package com.ivankatrump.jdbc;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Trump {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
    String username = "postgres";
    String password = "123456";

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

      // Step 2 - Open connection
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

      // Step 3 - Execute statement
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT version()");

      // Step 4 - Get result
      if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
      try {

        // Step 5 Close connection
        if (stmt != null) {
          stmt.close();
        }
        if (rs != null) {
          rs.close();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
          conn.close();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I am able to compile using `javac Trump.java` but when i try running it using `java Trump` then

i get the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Trump.class

This is what `echo %CLASSPATH%` looks like

`c:\donaldtrump>echo %CLASSPATH%`

```
c:\classpath\antlr-2.7.7.jar;c:\classpath\classmate-1.3.0.jar;c:\classpath\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;c:\classpath\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;c:\classpath\hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar;c:\classpath\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;c:\classpath\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;c:\classpath\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;c:\classpath\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;c:\classpath\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;c:\classpath\postgresql-42.1.4.jar
```

Why cant the system find Trump.class?

Edit

Compiling this way `c:\ivankatrump>javac -d . Trump.java` compiles but also dont run.

Comment: Why do you have the package set? `package com.donaldtrump.jdbc;`

Comment: I think the problem because classloader can't find class Trump in classpath, so try to add the distination of this class to classpath.

Comment: Thanks @agurylev that was the issue. I added to classpath and now works.

Comment: Maybe you could change the package Name from Donald Trump to anything else and it would work :)

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException Hold my beer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short explanation: 
try by creating folder `com`, `donaldtrump`, `jdbc`. Put the java class in there. Then,

```
javac com/donaldtrump/jdbc/Trump.java
java com/donaldtrump/jdbc/Trump
```

Better explanation:

[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)